# How to limit textField height?

Tags: jasper-reports

A have a *textField* and *subreport* placed at one detail band next to each other.

Code:

```xml
<band height="14" splitType="Stretch">
    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement style="cell" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="149" y="0" width="25" height="14" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
        <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
            <font fontName="Arial" size="6" isBold="false"/>
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{RZPR}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
    <subreport>
    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="802" height="14"/>
        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$F{CSR_SUB}]]></dataSourceExpression>
        <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "cashflowplan/sub_all.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
    </subreport>
</band>
```

Sometimes this leads to next situation:

screenshot:

[image]

*TextField* takes all the space available on the first page. But the *textFields* from *subreport's* *Detail* band move to the next page, leaving empty space at the end of the first page.

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: provide screen shots as possible

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: no, i have not.